# How to write a join query with like operator

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I'm trying to find duplicate ( matched names ) records in a table.

```
-----------------------------------
|id | name                        |
-----------------------------------
| 1 | Bielefeld Area, Germany     |
-----------------------------------
| 2 | Biella Area, Italy          | 
-----------------------------------
| 3 | Bilbao Area, Italy          | 
-----------------------------------
| 4 | Birmingham, United Kingdom  | 
-----------------------------------
| 5 | Blackburn, United Kingdom   | 
-----------------------------------
| 6 | Blackpool, United Kingdom   | 
-----------------------------------
| 7 | Bogotá D.C. Area, Colombia  |
-----------------------------------
```

i want to filter records which are repeated with same name like Birmingham United Kingdom , Blackburn United Kingdom , Bilbao Area Italy

result expected

```
-----------------------------------
|id | name                        |
-----------------------------------
| 2 | Biella Area, Italy          | 
-----------------------------------
| 3 | Bilbao Area, Italy          | 
-----------------------------------
| 4 | Birmingham, United Kingdom  | 
-----------------------------------
| 5 | Blackburn, United Kingdom   | 
-----------------------------------
| 6 | Blackpool, United Kingdom   | 
-----------------------------------
```

I have tried below query but not working.

```
select p.* 
from countries p
left join countries u
on concat('|', p.name, '|') like concat('%|', u.name, '|%')
```

Comment: None of those names are repeated in your sample data.

Comment: @Nick Yes, but i want to get matched records i.e, United Kingdom matches 3 times and Italy matches 2 time. check expected result table

Comment: Your question and expected result don't make sense to me. You seem to be saying give me everything where any distinct node in name appears more than once. How many nodes can there be BTW and are the always separated by comma?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` here:

`Select count(id) as count, name from countries group by countries.name`